# Grub2 cannot detect SSD but fdisk can

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, ssd, grub

I have a situation with my reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04.3 system. During boot stage up, it would stop at the "Grub vr2.02 beta2-36ubuntu3.14" screen, where the `grub>` prompt appears.

Initially, to boot successfully, I would first use `ls` and `cat (hdX,X)/etc/issue` to identify the disk with the Ubuntu 16.04.3 root partition and type:

```
set root=(hd2,2)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.XX.X.X.-XX-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p2
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.XX.X.X.-XX-generic
boot
```

Ubuntu would then boot up and shutdown correctly. However, during the next boot, the above cycle has to be repeated.

After a few such cycles, my system is now stuck at Grub2 again. Grub2 cannot locate my SSD device, i.e. `(hdX,X)/dev/nvme0n1` does not exist. However, when I use the  Ubuntu bootdisk to enter Ubuntu, I am able to see my SSD via `fdisk -l`, `Gparted` and `lsblk`. E.g.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1532116992 bytes, 2992416 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 447.1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1050624 870897663 869847040 414.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 870897664 937701375  66803712  31.9G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device     Start    End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 526335  524288  256M EFI System

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop1         7:1    0  83.1M  1 loop /snap/core/3247
sr0          11:0    1   1.5G  0 rom  /cdrom
loop0         7:0    0   1.4G  1 loop /rofs
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0   256M  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:6    0  31.9G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:4    0   512M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p2 259:5    0 414.8G  0 part
```

My SSD and HDD are using GPT and have a EFI partition. Also, my system's UEFI is configured to use EFI.

**Questions**:

1. How do I configure Grub2 to locate and connect with the SSD?
2. How do I fix the Grub boot so that Ubuntu can boot up
   automatically?

**Edit:** I do not know the technical steps behind answering my question, however I can share here what I did to recover from my situation. I installed linux mint in the other disk of my system. I did this because my Ubuntu installers had problem installing and I had a functioning Linux Mint installer in-hand. The idea was, if I could successfully install an equivalent OS that utilized grub2 as a bootloader, hopefully that success could fix my bootloading issues too. Fortunately, it worked! Grub2 does detect my SSD and Ubuntu 16.04.3 can boot up flawlessly.

Comment: In my case the opposite happens. Grub can find partition whereas Live CD cannot. Still stuck

Answer (score 0):

I found this [article explaining the grub2 repair,restore,reinstall process using a ubuntu-live-cd](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd). I think it gives the answer to my question.

Comment: Did this fix your problem? I suspect the problem is that the motherboard (the BIOS) initially is not detecting the ssd drive; it only does that after some kernel drivers are loaded. So I think that article you found, does not address the problem. Your grub installation is not broken; even though grub is installed on your ssd, initially control is transferred to a grub installed on a different drive. I have the same problem.